# Redshift cluster, how to get information of number of slice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

in our project we are using Redshift 4 node cluster.
Node type - `ra3.4xlarge`

i am not having superuser access on Redshift, so i can't query any system table on redshift.
could you please tell how to check how many slices in this cluster ?

i have tried to find out from AWS console also, not sure how to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Overview of Amazon Redshift clusters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html#working-with-clusters-overview) says that `ra3.4xlarge` has a default of **4 slices per node**.